# billboard.js multiple lines grouped by column json sourced

Tags: javascript, jquery, billboard.js

I'm driving crazy about this feature, I just need to draw 11 lines in a single chart. The data is a json sourced by ajax and I just get 3 column: index, label, value. The chart axes are index as x and values as y, for each label I need to draw his trend of values. Any hints?
A sample of input data:

```
{"data":[{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.56"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"99.76"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.62"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.72"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-16","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.90"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.56"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.38"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.62"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-17","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.71"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.56"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.45"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.72"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-18","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.56"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.52"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.72"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-19","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.67"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.27"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"98.78"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.44"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-20","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.86"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.80"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.67"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.49"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"98.84"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.44"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-21","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.80"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.69"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.49"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"98.68"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.47"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-22","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.73"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.49"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"98.60"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.47"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-23","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.80"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.43"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"98.60"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.47"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-24","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.80"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.43"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"98.68"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.47"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-25","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.73"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.79"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.43"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.49"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.01"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.47"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-26","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.80"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.88"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.67"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-27","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.93"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.54"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.75"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-04-28","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.75"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-29","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.94"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.75"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-04-30","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.88"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.75"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-01","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.54"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.82"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.67"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.87"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-02","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.93"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.54"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.82"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.75"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-03","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.93"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.31"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.52"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.51"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-04","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"98.99"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.31"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.58"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.51"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-05","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.26"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.77"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.75"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-06","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.80"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.90"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.89"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.82"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-07","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.93"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.91"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.89"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.83"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.71"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.74"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-08","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.69"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.82"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.77"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.71"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.65"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.74"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-09","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.75"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.77"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.81"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.82"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-10","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"99.81"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.88"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"III","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-11","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.82"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.84"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.66"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.53"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.46"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.48"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-12","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.71"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.84"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.89"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.58"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.46"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.48"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-13","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.83"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.86"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.77"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.72"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.46"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.48"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-14","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.88"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.65"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.89"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.53"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.41"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.48"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-15","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.83"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"AAA","Trend":"99.72"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"BBB","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"CCC","Trend":"99.89"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"DDD","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"EEE","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"FFF","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"GGG","Trend":"98.58"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"HHH","Trend":"99.41"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"III","Trend":"99.48"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"LLL","Trend":"100.0"},{"Index":"2023-05-16","SOM":"MMM","Trend":"99.88"}]}
```

This is my current code:

```
   $.when(post_api(get_chart))
    .done(function(res){

        var mychart = bb.generate({
            title: {
                text: "SOM Trend last "+points+" points",
                position: "center",
            },

            data: {
                json: res['data'],
                type: line(),
                x: "Index",
                columns: [
                    ["AAA"],
                    ["BBB"],
                    ["CCC"],
                    ["DDD"],
                    ["EEE"],
                    ["FFF"],
                    ["GGG"],
                    ["HHH"],
                    ["III"],
                    ["LLL"],
                    ["MMM"],
                ],
                keys: {
                    value: ["Index","SOM","Trend"],
                },
            },

            bindto: object,
            axis: {
                x: {
                  type: "timeseries",
                  tick: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d"
                  }
                }
            },
        });

    })
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, what doesn't work in your code ? Are you seeing any error in browser console ? Also, see if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jouah1dL/) helps.

Comment: It shows a wrong line chart, every index has all the points in his date intead of seprate the line by label. The AAA BBB etc are not columns but string of the same SOM column. I think I need to split his data before the chart declaration. Is it possible it does not exists a better way?

Comment: Can you please add excepted output in your question ?

Comment: I have solved it, my goal is draw 11 different lines on the same chart but the wrong result was the same time-index with all the point for date without split by SOM as my example.
After a foreach loop to have 11 different arrays init as AAA_x = ["AAA_index"], AAA_d = ["AAA"] and populated by a switch statement with this pseudo: AAA_x.push(index), AAA_d.push(trend)
The data statement of billboard.js is:
data: { type: line(), xs: { "AAA": "AAA_index", "BBB":"BBB_index", ... },
columns: [ AAA_x, AAA_d, BBB_x, BBB_d, ... ] }

Comment: I really don't wanted do as is, because I was looking on future development in which I will use the server side pagination and this kind of manipulation would be heavy for continous browsing. For now I can be happy to close this feature and make other tasks.

Comment: @Swati could you help me fixing this https://jsfiddle.net/3cu7vsyk/

Comment: Btw I have opened a new thread to make your hints dynamic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660461/billboard-js-columns-from-array